# solution needed to modify power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I want to find the power series for $\sqrt{x}$. I surf on the internet but there is no success.

I found some link from that I created power series of $\sqrt{x}$ as below ?

The link I refer is http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_15.htm and by replace $x$ by $x-1$ and alpha by $1/2$ as follow: $$\sqrt{x}=1+\frac{x-1}{2}-\frac{(x-1)^2}{8} + \frac{(x-1)^3}{64}+\cdots$$

but this is true in $-1 < x < 1$ what if I want $\sqrt{x}$ where $x$ can be any positive number like $2.5 , 6 , 7.9 , 22$ etc.

So can any one tell me the power series or what should I do to produce this series ?

Comment: You cannot find a Taylor series for $\sqrt{x}$ that converges for any positive $x$ because the radius of convergence will be limited by the distance of the center point to $0$.

Comment: I want to find power series not taylor series ?

Comment: @anorton can you pleae verify that above power series that I have written will work for number like 2.3 , 7,8 ,9.1 etc

Comment: The above power series you have written is a ***Taylor series***, and has radius of convergence $1$.  Thus, you can only plug in numbers in the range $[-1,1]$.  That is, you cannot plug in $2.3$, $7.8$, etc.

Comment: @anorton so if you know the power series can you tell me ? and also that would be great if I can plug in 2.3 , 7.8 , etc

Comment: Hmm... from some research, it appears the power series you're looking for is:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{\frac{1}{2}-n}(x-a)^n\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}$$
Where $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient, and $a$ is some number that is larger than the one you're plugging in.

Comment: For more info: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor+series+sqrt%28x%29+centered+at+x%3D5